# Permissions Denied in Terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

So I am a little new to working in the terminal and trying to set up yo and a localhost environment. No matter what I do it keeps throwing a permissions denied error. I have installed node and npm already and when I run the yo install 
npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp i get this error message. My buddy and I have tried so many different things to fix this but we cant get anywhere. I can access and run using sudo but I need to actually have the permissions to get this working. Help please?

I am sorry if that is not detailed enough, I am new to working in the terminal and may not know entirely what I am doing. If all else fails I was going to reset my desktop to factory settings and start over with setting my users and groups.

[Screenshot of errors Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Tp9.png)

Comment: did you try use ```sudo``` ? https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: yeah I tried sudo and thats the only way i can access or do anything, and I would prefer not to have to use sudo.

Comment: @KrzysztofSztompka I tried the video tutorial which is awesome thank you. It worked in that I could install yo without using sudo. But when I try to run yo i still get an EACCES permissions denied issue.

Comment: There is question and answer about EACCES in yeoman http://stackoverflow.com/a/31199516/4138339

Comment: It says I only have staff access and I am the admin, how is that??

NATHANIELEs-iMac:Users BigTuna$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrwxr-x+ 48 BigTuna  staff   1632 Oct 15 13:29 BigTuna
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 Guest    _guest   374 Jun 16  2014 Guest
drwxrwxrwt   7 root     wheel    238 Oct 11 17:02 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 16 imac     staff    544 Oct 15 11:40 imac

Comment: Im not a unix master (os x is also unix), but in os x by default you are not super user (roor user). Root user is disabled. You use normal user, and because that some actions need sudo permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

or

```
npm install npm -g
```

...will do the trick.

You're not the first one to experience those problems and they are (finally) actively addressed in `npm@3.X.X`